# Worin liegt der Unterschied zwischen "sich lösen" und "sich auflösen"?

Tags: meaning, difference

Wo liegt der Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen den oben genanten Wörter wenn es um eine Beschreibung der defekten Ware geht (Kleidungsstück)? Sagt man: *Das Material hat sich gelöst* oder *aufgelöst*? Was kann sich noch lösen/auflösen (immer im Kontext der Schäden)?

Answer (score 1):

*Lösen* kann sich ein Material vom anderen - Meist irgendwas, das an irgendwas anderem befestigt war - z.B. eine Schraube oder eine Applikation an einem Kleidungsstück. Englisch würde man *to loosen* sagen. Allerdings umfasst *lösen* auch die Bedeutung von *auflösen*, zumindestens bei der Auflösung von Dingen in Flüssigkeiten, das Nachfolgende gilt also zum großen Teil auch hier.

Von *auflösen* spricht man, wenn sich die Struktur eines Gegenstandes verflüchtigt, z.B. die von einem Stück Zucker in einer Tasse Kaffee oder eben das Gewebe eines Kleidungsstücks. Auf Englisch würde man *to dissolve* sagen.

Fun fact: Wenn *ein Hund sich löst*, ist dann ist das was ganz anderes. [Bitte selbst nachschauen](https://campogeno.wordpress.com/tag/hund-kackt/).

Comment: In der Fachsprache der Chemie wird häufig *lösen* verwendet, z.B. "Konzentrierte Salpetersäure löst Silber". "Auflösen" ist allerdings auch möglich.